# <script> Help on .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just recently got into coding and decided to just mess around before I started fully coding more in-depth. I am currently trying to make a simple game where you click an object, it does a little animation and it adds 1 to a counter.

I have the animation perfectly executed, however I am completely lost as to how I could make the counter. I am trying to use .js via the  tags, mainly because the website never loads my script.js file, even though I reference it properly.

Anyways here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>0 Clicks</h3>
    <img id="choco" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0210/5354/products/Chocolate_Chip_No_Background_1_medium.png?v=1365686508">
    <img id="whirl" src="whirl.jpg" style="width:25em; height:25em;">
</body>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    ('#cookie').click(function() {
        function toClick(clicks){
            return (clicks + 1);
        print clicks;
        };
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

My  is very messy, I was trying a plethora of options to try and get it to work but it simply doesn't.

So basically what I am trying to do, is everytime I click the object I want it to add 1 to a counter I have on the page.

#### 0 Clicks

I am not even sure that's possible but I hope someone out there can help me out :)

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see toClick being called

Comment: I don't see `print clicks` being valid Javascript.

Comment: I know, because I don't even know if that's needed :P I am completely lost at how i'm supposed to structure the script so it adds 1 when I click.

Comment: `#cookie` is a way of referencing (a jQuery wrapper) for the element with id='cookie', which you don't have. You might want #choco or #whirl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cookie').click(function() {
           incrementCount();
        });
    });

  function incrementCounter() {
          var previousCounter = parseInt($("#counter").text());
          previousCounter = isNaN(previousCounter) ? 0: ++previousCounter;

          $("#counter").text(previousCounter);
  }

  function resetCounter() {
     $("#counter").text(0);
 }
```

Change HTML to

```
<body>
    <h3><span id="counter">0</span> Clicks</h3>
```

The above code  will look after even if you don't specify 0 with the Span. 
I have just given you some bonus function - resetCounter too :)

Comment: EDIT: I am getting a console error saying theres an Unexpected token {, however I have looked through the code thoroughly and found nothing out of place

Comment: Please try now it should work

Comment: otherwise, instead of $("#counter").val use $("#counter").text everywhere... it always confuses me which framework you are on.

Comment: try with the latest now.

Comment: Aha! Found the errors, mistakenly I put "cookies" instead of "choco", and you had incrementCount() instead of incrementCounter()....works now! Thanks!

Comment: Haha true :). Chocho is better

Answer (score 3):

First, give your `h3` an inner element that holds the click counter (and give that an ID so you can access it easily):

```
<h3><span id="clicks">0</span> clicks</h3>
```

Next - your click handler is missing the `$` in front - but also has to get the current clicks, add 1, then re-print:

```
$('#cookie').click(function() {
    var currentClicks = parseInt($("#clicks").text(), 10);
    currentClicks++; //increment

    $("#clicks").text(currentClicks); //set it
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems You are missing the $ sing in:

```
    $('#cookie').click(function() {
```